# Riemann sum for unbounded functions

Tags: integration

Suppose that $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$ whose set of discontinuities is of Lebesgue measure zero. Is it true that the Riemann sum $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n)$ converges to $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$, as $n$ goes to infinity ? Remember that the $f$ may possibly be unbounded, and hence the Riemann integration theory fails.

Comment: Just an observation: Sets of measure zero can be dense (ie, the rational numbers) and so being continuous almost everywhere does not seems like that strong of a condition. I could be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Lebesgue integrable function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$, and modify it on $\Bbb Q$ so that
$$
x\in\Bbb Q\implies f(x) = 0
$$

As $\lambda(\Bbb Q) = 0$, the representation of $f$ in $L^1([0,1])$ does not change.

But the Riemann sums 
$$
S_n = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right)
$$are all null.

---

A more complex question is:

if for almost every choice of 
$$
\frac {k-1}n\le x_{k,n}\le \frac kn
$$the sums
$$
\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{k,n})
$$converge to $I$, then $I$ is the integral of $f$.

Comment: By changing the function on rational points, it may not remain continuous almost everywhere. So I am not sure that the construction works.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f$ on $(0,1]$ as follows:
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}
1/x,&1/x\in\mathbb N\,,\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\,.
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $(0,1]$, and $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$. However, for all $n\ge1$,
$$
\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^nf(j/n)\ge\frac1nf(1/n)=1\,.
$$ 
Therefore, the Riemann sums do not converge to zero.